# Функции: в каждой десятке элементов массива найти наименьшее значение и вывести ту часть массива, где минимум больше - C (СИ)

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Всем привет. Вот такое задание: Дан целочисленный массив A из 10*n элементов (n<=10). В каждой десятке найти наименьшее значение и вывести ту часть массива, где минимум больше. Для ввода, вывода массива и поиска минимума в одной части его использовать функции.
Вот мой код, но он соответственно не подходит. Я не могу переделать под условие. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int a[11];
    int min;
    int max;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0;i<11;i++)
    a[i]=rand() % 100 ;

    min = a[0];
    max = a[0];

    for (i=1;i<11;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        if (a[i] > max)
        {
            max = a[i];
        }
        else if (a[i] < min)
        {
            min = a[i];
        }
    }
printf("Min: %d\n", min);
printf("Max: %d\n", max);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что это Ваш код?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov С массивами мне тяжело разобраться. Этот код я нашел, но не могу его переделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, например:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    n = 15;  // Ну, или руками... scanf("%d",&n);

    int * a = malloc(n*10*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i*10; j < i*10+10; ++j)
        {
            a[j] = rand()%100 - 50; // Например...
        }
    }

    int min_idx = -1;
    int min_val = INT_MIN;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int min_ten = a[i*10]; // Минимальное значение в десятке

        for(int j = i*10+1; j < i*10+10; ++j)
        {
            if (min_ten > a[j]) min_ten = a[j];
        }
        if (min_ten > min_val)
        {
            min_val = min_ten;
            min_idx = i;
        }
    }
    assert((min_idx >= 0)&&("It is impossible!!"));

    for(int j = min_idx*10; j < min_idx*10 + 10; ++j)
        printf("%6d",a[j]);
    puts("");

}
```

Comment: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*', не могу найти ошибку

Comment: Да просто компилируйте код как С, а не как С++. Это все же разные языки :) А если все же хотите компилировать как C++, то `malloc` запишите как `(int*)malloc`. Просто вы написали - С, ну, я С и сделал...

Comment: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode. Я попробовал убрать int после скобки цикла. То есть оставил for(i=0; i<n; i++). И так везде. И в самом начале строчку int n; заменил на int n,i,j. При запуске выводит 36 40 11 -14 5 17 5 24 -19 2. Может я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: Да нет, вроде вы сделали корректно. А что вы хотели, чтоб выводило? *вывести ту часть массива, где минимум больше.* Находим в каждом десятке минимум, среди них - максимум. Там, где этот максимальный минимум - в данном случае, -19 - тот десяток и выводим...

Comment: Оххх. Я совсем запутался. Мы имеем 10 элементов. Что с ними происходит дальше я не понял. С самого начала я думал, что у нас к примеру 80 элементов массива и, скажем, пятый десяток элементов меньше остальных. Мы его и выводим. А что происходит в этой программе?

Comment: Что значит "пятый десяток меньше"? У вас же четко сказано - *В каждой десятке найти наименьшее значение и вывести ту часть массива, где минимум больше.* Я это и делаю. В каждом десятке ищу наименьшее значение. из этих минимумов выбираю наибольшее. Вывожу тот десяток, в котором находится это значение. Что опять не слава Богу? Вобщем, не нравится - пишите свой код, я написал, разжевал. Глотать за вас я не могу. На этом и закончим...

Comment: Я все понял. Спасибо, прошу прощения за беспокойство.